# Testing a Deployed Google DataStore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-datastore, service-discovery

I'm working on my first android app that uses a Google DataStore for the back end data storage. I've created a backend store and tested it uses the APIs Explorer and on localhost. I then created a project and deployed the backend to the cloud.

What I was expecting was to use the APIs Explorer to add some global configuration information and test the APIs. I typed in:
https://[projectID].appspot.com/_ah/api/explorer
which brings me to the explorer page but none of the services/endpoints show up.

I currently don't have any security defined for the project.

Can I use the API Explorer on a deployed backend? If so, I'm assuming I missed something in the project setup. Any ideas as to what I may have missed?

Thanks for your insights and answers.

Comment: Is your endpoints API defined in the default module?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yes, the deployed endpoints is the default module. 
I stumbled across a way to launch the API Explorer from within the Developers console. When I try, it asks me to activate the cloud datastore. When I following the link, none of the options make sense. The instructions are to activate the DataStore API from a Compute Engine instance. FYI, I have not enabled any API, nor created any credentials.
I can't see any difference between this project and a demo project (which works) that I found on the web a few months back.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `endpoints.API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID` in your api class decorator in case you need to view api in your deployed version.
Here's the example

```
@endpoints.api(name = '<api name>', 
               version = 'v1', 
               description = '<description>', 
               allowed_client_ids = [WEB_CLIENT_ID, ANDROID_CLIENT_ID,
               IOS_CLIENT_ID, endpoints.API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID], 
               audiences=[ANDROID_AUDIENCE], 
               scopes=[endpoints.EMAIL_SCOPE])
```

Hope this helps you.!